# Is it possible to get an activity result from an instrumentation test?

Tags: android, testing, android-espresso, robotium

I have an activity(A) in my app, which is started by an other activity(B) with startActivityForResult(). 
When a button is clicked in A, it will call setResult() and finish(), and go back to B.

How can I get that result from A, in my instrumentation tests?

I would like to keep it simple, and directly start A from my test, and not go trough B(and the activities before that).

I'm using robotium, and I've look into other tools too, and have not found anything useful.

getActivityMonitor().getResult() is null.
Robotium does not start the activity with startActivityForResult() anyway.
I don't want to mock the result from activity A, I want to check it's validity.

My current workaround is to read the value out of the activity with reflection, but there must be a better way.

Comment: So you want to run the activity A directly from the test and then clicks on a button?

Comment: I would like to test an activity, and check if the activityresult is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly try this

`Intent i = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), ActivityA.class);
    startActivity(i); //Start Activity A`

or you can make  the test star from specific activity

`public class ActivityATest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<ActivityA> {
...`

then in test  check

`// check that we have the right activity
solo.assertCurrentActivity("wrong activity", ActivityA.class);`

Comment: This is not enough. I have no problems with starting a specific activity, but I can't get the activityResult out of it.